# Grab specified columns from folder of CSVs

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, import, export-to-csv

Trying to grab only columns called "NAME" and "ROLE" from a folder of CSVs I converted from Excel.
All CSVs have NAME, ROLE, AGE, and TYPE. As the headers.

```
foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Z\Desktop\*csv"))
{
    $newname = $file.FullName -replace '\.xls$', '.csv'
    $ExcelWB = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Workbook = $ExcelWB.Workbooks.Open($file.FullName)
    $Workbook.SaveAS($newname, 6)
    $Workbook.Close($false)
    $ExcelWB.Quit()
}
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Z\Desktop\*.csv"
Get-Content $files | Set-Content "C:\Users\Z\Desktop\combined.csv"
```

So far I have successfully created one large CSV called combined to combine them all.

I know something along the lines of when importing but when I tried the import method my file is blank.

```
| Select "NAME" and "ROLE"
```

Can be used but uncertain of the syntax.
I want to be able to output 1 large combined CSV (NAME, ROLE) and then have individual CSVs outputted with an additional column where the rows came from (NAME, ROLE, FILENAME).

Comment: like this ? Get-Content $files | Select "GRANTEE" and "GRANTEE_ROLE" | Set-Content "C:.....

Comment: why would you use a `select-object` on "GRANTEE" and "GRANTEE_ROLE" - are we missing something from the original post?

Comment: Also in your foreach you can also just do `foreach($file in $files)` as you've declared it already in a variable.